# Wordpress custom query: 'orderby' => 'date' not working when using multiple post types

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

In a Wordpress page template, I set up a WP custom query which queries a  custom post type named "recipe" AND the regular posts as below. This works, but `'orderby => 'date'` in there doesn't work: The page first lists the regular posts ordered by date, then the recipes by date. But I need ALL of them together (i.e. mixed) ordered by date.

Here's the definition of my custom query:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$number_of_posts = get_option('posts_per_page', 12);

$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('recipe', 'post'),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'paged' => $paged
);
$my_loop = new WP_Query($args);

[...followed by the loop...]
```

I am grateful for any hints what I can do to achieve the desired ordering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution myself:

It works when I add `remove_all_filters('posts_orderby');` before the custom query is defined. Obviously this resets any other ordering and allows the `'orderby' => 'date'` to function as expected. Complete code:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$number_of_posts = get_option('posts_per_page', 12);

remove_all_filters('posts_orderby'); // ADDED

$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('recipe', 'post'),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'paged' => $paged
);
$my_loop = new WP_Query($args);

[...]
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks so much for coming back and posting your solution.

Comment: really weird - my query didn't seem to have any additional query ordering, but this helped

Comment: This issue randomly occurred for me with a recent core update, I was scratching my head for a while, this worked a treat, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Q1. what template file are you using?

The query below successfully merges the 2 post types together by date.

```
<?php
        $args = array(
          'post_type' => array('my_custom_post_type', 'post'),
          'posts_per_page' => -1,
          'order' => 'DESC',
          'orderby' => 'date',

        );
         $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
          while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post(); ?>
           // loop your content here
        <?php include(locate_template('templates/content.php')); ?>
        <?php
        }
        } else {
          // no posts found
        }
        /* Restore original Post Data */
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
```

Comment: I am using a custom template file which i wrote myself. The loop in that template is basically similar to your answer, except that my content fetching happens directly in that file, not in an included template-part. But there's no difference concerning the orderby and post_type details, and that is what doesn't work as expected. Nevertheless, thanks for taking the time to answer!